# Xcode/iOS 5 - Rounding only bottom 2 corners of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5, rounded-corners

For the UI of the app I'm working on, I'm trying to create rounded corners for the view controller. I have a UINavigationBar and a UITableView. I've already rounded the top 2 corners of the UINavigationBar manually by using a custom background with UIAppearance stuff. Now I want to round the **bottom 2** corners of the UITableView so it looks nice. The code I have right now rounds all 4 corners. Anyone know how I can only round the bottom 2?

Here's what I have added right now in my ViewDidLoad method of the UITableViewController. And I have QuartzCore imported.

```
    _tasksTableView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
```

**Thanks a ton to anyone that can help out!**

Answer (score 2):

You could create new CAShapeLayer and set its path to be a bezierPath created with

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect 
                          byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners 
                                cornerRadii:(CGSize)cornerRadii
```

Byt setting the corners to `(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)` your new layer will have rounded corners in the two bottom corners.

Next you mask the _tasksTableView.layer with the shape layer you just created by setting the `mask` property on the table view layer.

---

*Note: the shape layer should **not** be have any super layer.*

*Note: the bezier path needs to be converted to a CGPathRef by calling `CGPath` on the bezier path before setting it as the `path` property of the shape layer.*